# Context free grammar for language

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I'm learning how to generate `context-free grammar` for a `language`.

$L=\{{a}^i {b}^j {c}^k\, |\,i=j\lor j=k$

Here is how I tried to solve it. First I take a quick look at what words I can generate with such a language.

Same number `a`s than `b` or `c` but not both. Meaning that if `i = 0` then `i = j = 0` but `k != 0`.

```
{c, b, ab, ac, aabb, aacc, abbc}
```

So I need a rule for generate either a number of `c`s or `empty`

${C\rightarrow cC\,|\,\epsilon}$

Same for `b`

${B\rightarrow bB\,|\,\epsilon}$

And then a rule that either generate the same number of `a`s than `b`s and any number `c`s

${S\rightarrow abC\,|\,acB}$

And all together

$${S\rightarrow abC\,|\,acB}$$
$${B\rightarrow bB\,|\,\epsilon}$$
$${C\rightarrow cC\,|\,\epsilon}$$

Is my approach right?

Answer (score 0):

The language $L$ has strings $a^ib^jc^k$, where $i=j$ or $j=k$.

Your approach isn't quite right. The rule ${S\rightarrow abC\,|\,acB}$ allows you to make only one $a$ and in the other option the $b$'s go to wrong place.

Think it like this: when you want to generate a word, you must first choose if there are equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s or equal number of $b$'s and $c$'s.

Have you tried to do easier exercises like the languge $\{ a^nb^n \mid  n\geq 0\}$?